# Apache Ignite incorrect node discovery when running on AWS EC2 in docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I am running several instances of Spring Boot applications with Apache Ignite nodes embedded into my applications. The applications is started in docker container on EC2 instances.

For discovery I am using S3 based approach described here:
https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/amazon-aws

My problem is that IP addresses stored in S3 bucket is invalid. I assume application within docker have different IP comparing to real EC2 instance IP.

So my question is: how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After week of investigation I realize the only possible way is to use ELB based discovery:
https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/amazon-aws#amazon-elb-based-discovery

The S3 discovery is not working for my case as IP addreses of nodes is resolved incorrect due to nodes are running withing docker container.

Comment: Hi Alex, did you used community ami for apache ignite in ec2 ? or you used this blog to build the ignite ec2 ? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/real-time-in-memory-oltp-and-analytics-with-apache-ignite-on-aws/

Comment: @sriharikalicharanTummala apache ignite was running in server mode within each entity, probably it is third option )))